# XCode 6.4 debugging not working unless manually attach to iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging

I'm trying to debug an iOS project in XCode 6.4. Recently, none of the breakpoints are working (they did before), while I'm running the iOS Simulator. The debugging area only starts if I manually attach it to the process. I've looked through the project build scheme and settings, and there's nothing to suggest that I've turned off or changed the debugger in any way.

The problem only occurs with this specific project in XCode. I even reinstalled XCode to no avail, so I assume the problem must be specific to this project/workspace.

Any ideas why the debugging is not automatically attaching to the process? Or a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to relaunch Xcode and restart mac?

Comment: I did, but didn't work. I even reinstalled XCode, but that didn't help anything either...

Comment: Try also: Simulator -> Reset content and settings...

Comment: Just tried that again, no luck.

Comment: Is this problem only with your single app? What happens if you try to create new project and debug it?

Comment: It's a problem only with this app. Creating a new project let's me debug normally.

Comment: only thing that I can advice is create new project and migrate code from your current project to new one.